# OnStateChange triggered once, when you select other videos, the onStateChange doesn't trigger again

Tags: youtube

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('YT_Video', {
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

if(event.data == 1){
alert("Playing);
}
```

This works in first video, but if you select the other video, that function cannot triggered again.

I expected that everytime I select other videos or iFrame, the onStateChange triggered, but it triggered only once